# Birkhoff-Grothendieck confusion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I encountered what looks like a contradiction to the Birkhoff-Grothendieck theorem, so I am hoping somebody can point out where I am confused.

Let $\ell \subset V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a line contained in a hypersurface of degree $d$. In $\mathbb{P}^n$, $\ell$ is the transverse intersection of $n-1$ hyperplanes, so its normal bundle is
$$N_{\mathbb{P}^n/\ell} \cong (n-1)[H]\big|_\ell = \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus n-1}.$$
But we also have 
$$N_{\mathbb{P}^n/\ell} \cong N_{V/\ell} \oplus N_{\mathbb{P}^n/V} = N_{V/\ell} \oplus d[H]\big|_\ell = N_{V/\ell} \oplus \mathcal{O}(d).$$
By Birkhoff-Grothendieck, $N_{V/\ell}$ factors as a sum of line bundles, giving a factorization of $N_{\mathbb{P}^n/\ell}$, and further that factorization is supposed to be unique up to reordering. How does one factorization have an $\mathcal{O}(d)$ summand while the other does not?

Comment: How do you know that $\mathcal{O}(d)$ is a direct summand? Exact sequences need not split even if all the vector bundles occurring are direct sum of line bundles. B-G does not say they split.

Comment: @Mohan Aha! Thanks. I'm still not used to the holomorphic category. So we have a non-split exact sequence $N_{V/\ell} \hookrightarrow N_{\mathbb{P}^n/\ell} \twoheadrightarrow N_{\mathbb{P}^n/V}$. Now that I think about it, is the other half of my logic accurate, that the normal bundle of a transverse intersection is the sum of the normal bundles? Does that require extra hypotheses in the holomorphic category (like a complete intersection)?

Comment: Can you explain what sequence you are considering, which you want to split?

Comment: Given complex submanifolds $H_1, H_2 \subset M$ instersecting transversely, the sequence $N_{M/H_1} \hookrightarrow N_{M/H_1 \cap H_2}  \twoheadrightarrow N_{M/H_2}$.

Comment: These split.  Also, most authors use $N_{Y/X}$ for  normal bundle of $Y\subset X$ unlike your $N{X/Y}$.

Comment: Why do they split? And thanks for the note.

Comment: You can read them in any book dealing with it and fairly trivial.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the error in the arguments above. The normal bundle to $\ell$ is not a direct sum$$N_{\ell/V} \oplus N_{V/\mathbb{P}^n}.$$For this to be true the line should be a section of $V$ by a some linear $2$-space, which is possible only if$$\deg V = 1.$$